# Clicking a Bootstrap Nav Tab won't scroll to Tab Pane - jQuery / Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some Bootstrap vertical tabs that I'm struggling with what I felt like would be a simple operation.

### Goal:

On the click of Tab, I want to smooth-scroll to the corresponding pane.

### What's Actually Happening:

On click of the tab, the browser animates to the **tab**, not the tab pane. I've tried passing in the `paneId` instead of the ID, but that doesn't work at all. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

### Codepen:

Here's a Codepen: [Codepen!](https://codepen.io/Sackadelic/pen/OJWYMjP?editors=0001)

### jQuery:

```
$("#tabs .nav-link").click(function (e) { //on click of nav tav, perform this:
    var id = $(e.target).prop("id"); //Grab ID of .nav-link clicked
    var paneId = id.replace("tab", "pane"); //Replace "tab" with "pane" and assign new var

    function navigateToElement(id) {
        $("html, body").animate(
            {
                scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
            },
            300
        );
    }
    navigateToElement(id); //Tried with "paneId" instead of "id" to scroll to the pane, but doesn't work
});
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var paneId = id.replace("tab", "pane"); //Replace "tab" with "pane" and assign new var
```

Is creating a variable like: `v-pills-profile-pane` and there isn't a div on the page with that id. I did see a div with `id="v-pills-profile"`. Change that last line to this and it should work:

```
var paneId = id.replace("-tab", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that it doesn't matter what pane I scroll to, as bootstrap will display the panes under `#panes`. As long as I can scroll to that, I'm good. This code worked:

```
$("#tabs .nav-link").click(function (e) {
    var target = $("#panes");

    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate(
      {
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 20, // added a bit of offset
      },
      350
    );
  });
```